# window.ethereum is always null (with metamask installed)

Tags: metamask

I'm trying to create a 'connect to metamask' button using their tutorial but the "window.ethereum" variable is always null even if metamask is installed / unlocked.

I'm not quite sure where to go from here. It seems metamask is supposed to inject Ethereum into the browser

Using chrome as shown below

[image]

Comment: try to open regular site first. Like google.com and check it there. Should work. I suppose you try it in MetaMask tab which is not correct.

Comment: Did you try window.web3?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but on Firefox. I didn't managed to fix that issue on a an ordinary Firefox, I downloaded Firefox for developers, downloaded Metamask there and had the same issue again. In my extension manager though (in Firefox for developers) i set this option for my Metamask:[image]

And it seemed to fix the problem!